# Why Angular.js promise is better than callbacks in javascript

Tags: angularjs

We are using Angular JS promises heavily and its one of the recommend practice from Angular team also. I feel that its just a syntax sugar on the top of Callback. But not sure about it. Can anybody give me few examples where Angular.js promises are better than javascript callbaks?

Comment: I believe **angular promise** is better because if reduce burden of many callbacks. Same approach is in **Nodejs** instead of callback **Modular** or **Promises** approach is recommended.

Comment: http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/ details why promises are superior to callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises can be chained and avoid the 'pyramid of doom'. They also have a defined way of handling results like success and failures, which with callbacks is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple ajax calls and on each success of those calls sometimes you have to call the same ajax method again. Coding such scenario becomes ugly with callbacks.

Promise handles that very elegantly.